# Discord.py | Member list

Tags: python, discord.py, typeerror

I need to get the list of all users on my discord server. I tried this code but I got an error.
How can I do this?

First I tried to get all members and put it into a .txt file.

```py
def get_users(self):
   with open('users.txt','w') as f:
      for member in discord.Guild.fetch_members(limit=150):
         print("{}".format(member.name), file=f)
```

Then I put it into **init** function cause I need to get this list when the bot is started up.

```py
class BotBanners(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        BotBanners.get_users_avatars(self)
        BotBanners.generate_main_banner(self)
```

I got an error and I can't find anything about that.

**Error**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 48, in <module>
    bot.load_extension('cogs.{}'.format(filename[:-3]))
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 664, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 624, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.BotBanners' raised an error: TypeError: fetch_members() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `fetch_members` on the `Guild` class like a static method, but you need to call it on an instance of a guild. Most likely you'll want to just get that guild by ID, or loop through the bot's guilds.